# Preprocessing Pandas Column: Iterator versus List

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a pandas dataframe where each row contains a sentence. I want to preprocess each sentence, getting rid of non-English words. Would it be (and if so, how much) slower to convert the column to an iterator versus converting the column to a list or doing an .apply on the column? The data frame must be stored in memory; additionally, converting the column to a list in memory would cause the memory to overflow. More explicitly:

Code Block 1:

```
def preprocessWrapper(df, col):
   newls = [] 
   ls = df[col].values.tolist()
   for x in ls:
       newls.append(preprocess(x))
   return newls
```

Code Block 2:

```
def preprocessWrapper(df, col):
    return df[col].apply(lambda x: preprocess(x))
```

Code Block 3:

```
def preprocessWrapper(df, col):
       newls = [] 
       itr = iter(df[col])
       while True:
           try:
               x = next(itr)
               newls.append(preprocess(x))
           except:
               return newls
```

Would code block 3 be slower than code block 1,2? And if so, why?

Comment: I don't understand your third block. You create an iterator and you don't use it? It's probably better to use a list comprehension or if it's not fast enough, use `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Sorry, typo in the code. I fixed it!

Comment: `try/except` will be slower than no check. `append` method can get slow with many records. Use a comprehension or second block or multiprocessing

Comment: I am interested in how these three code blocks compare against each other. I understand multiprocessing would provide better performance. I am using an iterator because there is a memory constraint.

Comment: Why is the wrapper needed? Can't you just use `df[col] = df[col].map(preprocess)`

Comment: I guess it is not needed. It is there more for readability. Wouldn't map be the same as apply?

Comment: Have you got a look on [Vectorized String Operations](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.10-working-with-strings.html). Not clear, what’s your task for string preprocessing.

Comment: Please provide more information about what you want to do (code behind `process`) and constraints (memory, number of records, etc).

Comment: @Corralien append isn't slow, indeed, a list comprehension is just a Python loop that appends to a list

Comment: Code block 3 only processes a single element in the iterator, it doesn't make any sense. I think you have a misunderstanding surrounding iterators. In any case, ther is no reason to explicitly create an iterator here.

Comment: Fundamentally, though, *you should be profiling the different approaches to see which is faster* (of course, after making sure they are doing the same thing)

Comment: I updated the post to provide some more information and fix the bug @juanpa.arrivillaga noted.

Comment: Why would you use a `while` loop and not a form loop? What is the *point* of explicitly making an iterator here? Why not `for x in df[col]`? Again, you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding

Comment: It would almost certainly be more efficient to use pandas built-in string operations; there's not much you can do in straight Python that you can't do with them. If you were to share your `preprocess` code you could probably get a vectorised answer which would be much more efficient than any of the solutions you propose.

Comment: For each row, I split the string into a list of words and compare each word against a predefined dictionary.  Any word that is not within the dictionary is deleted. I do not think this operation (beyond the split) can be vectorized.

Comment: I am simply interested in how creating an iterator for a pandas column compares to other operations. I understand it will be slower, but I am trying to understand if that has to do with the iterator having to access the data frame constantly or something else.

Comment: *I do not think this operation (beyond the split) can be vectorized*. Probably but it's not obvious without a minimal working example. However, you can parallelize your code with a pool of workers.